# Animating NSDrawer

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

How can I open and close a drawer in a Cocoa Application using a smooth animation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`NSDrawer` animates be default. You just need to call the relevant methods, or bind its state property to a button.

[Apple doc](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSDrawer_Class/Reference/Reference.html)